# how to make a gridview printable in colors in aspx?

Tags: asp.net, printing, colors, grid

I want to make a grid that the users will print and that will display it's rows in different colors on the printable version
I'm using ASPX

It seems that even you make the colors right, when you print it , the colors are disapearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IE, this is a browser setting.  In IE, under Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Printing you will see a setting called "Print background colors and images".